# Get Windows 7 to remember my multi-monitor configuration and automatically restore windows when reconnected

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm looking a way to enable one feature: when I disconnect one of my monitors (e.g. to do a presentation with a projector), when I come back and reconnect that monitor, restore all my windows to where they were before I disconnected. In this case I've only got my desktop monitor and 1 (of many) projectors to remember, but ideally the software could remember as many setups as necessary. It would be nice if it could group configurations (e.g. built-in screen + high resolution external, built-in + low resolution external) rather than having a setup for every projector I might ever have connected to.

Is there any way Windows 7 can do that? I haven't found anything in Windows that appears to provide that functionality. I'd have thought that after at least 15 years of supporting multiple monitors, I can't be the only person who's tired of having all their applications jumbled up just because I had to connect to a projector for a presentation. All the third-party software I've looked at seems to require me to manually create and switch between profiles and don't seem to be able to automatically select one based on connecting a specific monitor configuration. They also expect that I'm going to take the time to assign specific applications to specific monitors, but what I really want is for the computer to just remember which window was on which monitor and what state it was in the last time this configuration was connected (there's already a UI built in to Windows allowing me to indicate which application windows I want on which screen -- it's the Windows Shell and Desktop Windows Manager).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please know that your question is [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as this site does not offer purchase recommendations.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear that I don't need a purchase recommendation, just a way to make Windows 7 a little intelligent about how it handles multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IconRestorer

Or Midi-ox Desktop Restore

Both are fine with W7 and do what you want. I won't provide links (since they die). Google either, or Google the search term `windows 7 save desktop layout`