# Windows 7: any way to restore application postition and sizes after switching from/to dual monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

At work we're setup with a laptop (lenovo) with dock and two external monitors, but often I have to undock. Every time I undock all open application windows move to the primary monitor (on the laptop) which makes sense so applications are accessible. The problem is when I redock I have to rearrange all my (6+) applications, which is a *small* hassle.

Is there any utility or configuration or application I can use to assign and restore a default position for applications in windows 7? Just to help avoid rearranging everything manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate (No answers): [Get Windows 7 to remember my multi-monitor configuration and automatically restore windows when reconnected](http://superuser.com/questions/609066/get-windows-7-to-remember-my-multi-monitor-configuration-and-automatically-resto?rq=1)

Comment: Another duplicate (no answers): [Automatically restore windows as monitors are connected and disconnected?](http://superuser.com/questions/636687/automatically-restore-windows-as-monitors-are-connected-and-disconnected?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm) from DeskSoft could handle this. It lists "multiple profiles" as a feature, so I'm assuming you could have a *Docked* profile and an *Undocked* profile, for example.

**Disclaimer:** I have no experience with this application whatsoever.

http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm